# How to call python script file under PHP?

Tags: php, python, python-2.7

I have two files in the same directory:

```
index.php
excel.py
```

I tried to call `excel.py` in file `index.php` like:

```
$buff = system('python excel.py ' . $handle->file_dst_pathname, $retval);
```

I use Windows 10

Comment: What happened when you tried? Was there an error message? What webserver are you using?

Comment: No any errors, I think I have to specify full path to file (d:\path) then after gap: `d:\path python excel.py`

Comment: I try that under windows

Comment: Python file in windows must be in python directory `C:\python27\> python file.py`

Comment: I have installed that as global PATH and can run everywhere

Comment: `exec("C:\Python27\python.exe C:\dir...\file.py")` have you tried it like this?

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you. Post this as answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this,

```
exec("C:\Python27\python.exe C:\dir...\file.py");
```

The problem is you must call `C:\Python27\python.exe` Python exe file
 before python file.